# TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined doPost

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram

Currently I'm working with my script that can search a data from google sheet by sending a keyword in telegram but I have eerror with my script.

***Error***
TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined
doPost

***Error Line***

```
function doPost(search) {
  var stringJson = search.postData.getDataAsString();
  var updates = JSON.parse(stringJson);
 
    if(updates.message.text){
      sendText(updates.message.chat.id,SearchIDSheet(updates.message.text)); 
    }
}
```

***SEND***

```
function sendText(chatid,text,replymarkup){
var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMessage",
      chat_id: String (chatid),//(chatid),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(replymarkup)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + BotToken + '/', data);
}
```

May I know what I need to change or modify with the script for me to resolve this error?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide how you are sending the data

Comment: Hi @WaximCorp I update the details above let me know if you need more information

Comment: try this -> payload: JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: Hi @WaximCorp, where should I add it?

Comment: the data in your payload must be pass to JSON.stringify function.. So something like this (you have to complete) : `var data = { method: "post", payload: JSON.stringify({ method: "sendMessage", ... })}; `